# Unable to click some hyperlinks due to css formatting

Tags: html, css

My final is to recreate a basic html page with my own css like csszengarden.com.
I made a simple one page deal at http://randallmiller.pcriot.com/72bclass/final72b/index.html.
However a few of my links are not clickable. Here is the css for the site. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I fixed the unclickable part with z-index:1, I think because of the padding on linkblock2. However, now my a:hover to turn them grey is only working for a few.

```
html{
    height:100%;
}

body{
    background:#000000;
}

h3{
    margin-top:0;   
}

h3 span{
    color:white;
    display:block;
}

.pgtitle1{
    word-spacing:10px;
    padding-top:25px;
    margin-left:125px;
    font:1.5em "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.pgtitle2{
    padding-top:10px;
    margin-left:275px;
    font:bold .7em "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
    letter-spacing:2px;
}

div#linkblock1{
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    padding-left:25%;   
}

div#linkblock2{
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    padding-left:67.5%;
}

div a{
    border-bottom:solid 1px white;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    display:block;
    width:90px; 
}

div a:hover{
    color:rgb(200,200,200); 
}

div a:visited{
    color:blue; 
}

div#fg_img{
    height:323px;
    background:url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center;
    margin-top:50px;
    line-height:999;
    overflow:hidden;    
}

h2{     
    font-size:.75em;
    color:#FFF;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:60px;  
}
```

Comment: Test this in a [text browser](http://www.delorie.com/web/lynxview.html). Making things pretty with CSS is all very well, but the page should be sane without the stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

You've covered up some of your links with `#fg_img`. Set some `z-index`es.

Comment: Thank you, is this a possibility why my a:hover isn't working on some of the links also?

Comment: You've defined `:visited` after `:hover` so if a link is visited then the `:visited` styles will override the `:hover` styles.

Answer (score 0):

Your divs are overlapping each other in many weird ways, the position:absolute on the div with the right links "linkblock2" is overlapping the links on the left.

You should really remove the position:absolute and use float on the divs, and you wouldn't run into that problem.

Not  sure if it's an option or not, but check out a CSS Grid system if you can use it on your assignment.

Comment: Got it, I will check out the grid system. Thank you!